# Disable parent div, and display only children div?

Tags: html, css, joomla

I'm working on Joomla sidebar of rockettheme templates and I want to disable all properties of parent `div` `module-inner3` (disable `background`, `padding`, `border`… etc), only display children `div` `customright_content`.

I can do it by replacing all code from `right_content` to `module-inner3` in template.css, but the issue is that I need to reuse `module-inner3` for other pages, so if I replace that, it's gonna break all other pages.

Is there a way I can solve this?

HTML code:

```
<div class="module-inner3">
<div class="customright_content">
blablad
</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
module-inner3{
background: url("../images/shadows/light/module-top2.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 0 transparent;
padding: 15px 6px 0 6px;
}

customright_content {
background: url("../images/background.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 0 transparent;
}
```

Comment: you could change class using jquery or remove it at all. But it will work only if you dont use `module-inner3` class anyware else on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely certain there are no styles you want to keep, then just removing the class from that div would do. However, I would lean to adding a class (you can come up with a better name than illustrated here), just because then, if you have other styles you want to remain in place from `.module-inner3` (a float, position, etc.) you can keep those.

```
<div class="module-inner3 override"> 
  <div class="customright_content"> 
    blablad 
  </div> 
</div>
```

```css
.module-inner3 { 
   background: url("../images/shadows/light/module-top2.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 0 transparent; 
   padding: 15px 6px 0 6px; 
}

.module-inner3.override {
   background: none;
   padding: 0;
}

.customright_content { 
   background: url("../images/background.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 0 transparent; 
}
```